# Jquery hide div and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code on jsfiddle which has 2 divs, where the user can select features by clicking on a div. in the opposite div i have the same item but hidden. how can i replace the hidden class?

this is what i have come up with:

```
$("#Label1").click(function () {
    $(this).find('.feature-options1').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().closest('.feature-container').prev().find('#SelectedFeatures').find('#Label2').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6xcj/9/

Comment: Why are you using complex selectors and find() to end up with an element that has an ID, a unique identifier there is only one element that would match ?

Comment: wouldn't this would do the same: `$('#Label2').removeClass('hidden');`

Answer (score 0):

is this:

```
$(this).find('.feature-options1').hide();
$('#label2').find('.feature-options1').show();
```

what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, I failed a bit, changed it now. hehe

Answer (score 0):

You should use .parent() not .prev() to get the containing div

```
$("#Label1").click(function () {
    $(this).find('.feature-options1').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().closest('.feature-container').parent().find('#SelectedFeatures').find('#Label2').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5W48X/

.prev() gives you the previous sibling element.

.parent() gives you the container (parent) element.

EDIT:

I had not even seen the id's you use on divs yet. This should work as well:

```
$("#Label1").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    $('#Label2').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Zbsa/

Comment: Like Adeneo said, you should make use of simple element selection. So if you use id's in your HTML, you should use them in your javascript. I would like to add that I would not use id's like this personally. It's better to use classes which are traversed, to maintain a more general solution. In addition, the show and hide example is also good, but should start by initiating the element with a hide() call.

Comment: If you think your question is answered, please mark my answer as such. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#Label1").click(function () {
            $(this).find('.feature-options1').addClass('hidden');
            $(this).parent().next().next().find('#Label2').removeClass('hidden');
        });
```

Try this i may help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".feature-addons").on('click', function(e){
        var lbl = $(this).next();
        $(".feature-addons").next().addClass('hidden');
        lbl.removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```